# C self assignment in functions

Tags: c, gcc, legacy, qnx

Porting some legacy C code from QNX (Photon C compiler) to Linux (GCC). In several places I see code like this:

```
void process_data(char key, char *data)
{
    int i;

    /* Required for compilation */
    i=i;
    key=key;
    data=data;

    ...
}
```

Obviously this code is NOT required for compilation and it does nothing.

My question is why would you ever do this in the first place?

Comment: To shut up the compiler that warned about using uninitialised variables, maybe. But that's pure unmitigated evil.

Comment: Perhaps they were building with warnings enabled for unused variables/arguments and warnings being treated as errors.

Comment: Writing code like that to shut up a warning is like covering your "check engine" light with a piece of a electrical tape.  The warnings are there for a reason.  I'd remove that code, compile it, and see what happens.  Let us know, will you?

Comment: @AndyLester that's why normally this code isn't automatically injected but manually put there after inspection. There are situations when you don't need the variable, e.g. if you have a common handler for various operations and for some operations the parameter isn't needed

Comment: @icepack: I'm very familiar with the problem, and in those cases you should use a macro to make it explicit what the intent is, as discussed below.

Comment: @AndyLester so I misunderstood your comment. Maybe like the code above it's not verbose enough? :)

Comment: If `i` isn't used, I simply won't declare it. For `key` and `data` that's a different story though ...

Comment: @icepack: If someone reading the code has to say "Why is this written this way?" then there is inadequate commenting.  `/* Required for compilation */` is an inadequate comment because it didn't explain enough for the reader (you) to understand.

Comment: @AndyLester I understand the comment in the code and the code, I didn't understand your comment to the question...

Comment: @AndyLester removing the self assignment code is harmless in GCC. +1 for electrical tape comment

Comment: @icepack very insightful. turns out we have several programs linked against a "library" c file where we have a common handler for several operations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This removes compilation warnings/errors about unreferenced variables. Usually such stuff is done either by `#pragma`s or by a more expressive form, such as macro: `#define unused_var(x) (x)=(x)`

Comment: GCC also supports `__attribute__((__unused__))`.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html for more. (an

Comment: I prefer this macro : `#define unused_var(x) (void)(x);` used by Qt

Comment: I bet there dozens of ways to do this but nice suggestions :)

Comment: In the Parrot project, I have it use both, depending on compiler.  The `UNUSED(x)` macro uses the `__attribute__((__unused__))` if it's supported, and the `(void(x)` if not.